# How to get page height of a react page

Tags: reactjs, height

I would like to get the height of a page in React after all content is rendered. 
The page is built dynamically (with post apis) so the content takes a few ms to load.

I tried to get the height in the *componentDidMount* function with :

```
var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
          var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
              html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
```

But is doesn't work (it gives me a small height, no the full page)

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean the height of the viewport or the height that the entire page is supposed to have ?

Comment: I mean the height of the entire page.
Because actually I send this information to a website where the content is loaded through an iframe, and to fit it dynamically to the height without scrollbars.

Comment: Wait so what you want to do is, get the height of an entire page, after loaded, so that you can insert it into an iframe and have the iframe be the full height to avoid scrollbars ?

Comment: That's it! But what is more complicated is that when you navigate into the iframe, the height changes and the iframe has to update its height automatically. To send this info each time the page changes I used event.data and `postMessage`. It works well except that I can't figure to find the height of the entire page for each page (when a new component is loaded)